# display buttons for few seconds and then reset screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a piece of code that makes my counter work for 2 minutes. after 2 min are over an alert box appears informing about the time completion.

What i am trying to do is that when the alert box appears and user clicks ok and returns to the screen i want to make 2 buttons disappear and only one button should stay. Till here i have been able to do but this part(also indicated through comment b/w the code) should stay only for 20 seconds and after that the screen should get reset automatically.

The code that i am using is

```
    var ticker = function() 
        {
            counter--;
            var t = (counter / 60) | 0; // it is round off
            digits.eq(0).text(t);
            t = ((counter % 60) / 10) | 0;
            digits.eq(2).text(t);
            t = (counter % 60) % 10;
            digits.eq(3).text(t);
            if (!counter) 
                {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    alert('Sorry, time is out.');

/***3 lines given below should stay for 20 sec and after that the screen should get reset***/ 

                        $("#count").hide(); 
                        $("#walkaway").show(); 
                        $("#submitamt").hide();


                }
        };
```

Comment: Where's the full code? Can't find `setInterval()`!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Does this work?

```js
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert("Alert came after 2 mins.");
    $(".after-2mins").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
      location.href = location.href;
    }, 2000);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<p>Wait for 2 mins. 5 seconds in this demo.</p>
<div class="after-2mins hidden">
  <p>2 mins over. Displaying 2 buttons. After 20 seconds, everything will reload. It is 2 seconds in this demo.</p>
  <input type="button" value="Button1" />
  <input type="button" value="Button2" />
</div>
```

Comment: it didnt work, as my buttons are placed in different places therefore cant bind them under one div

Comment: You can add a few more classes or use the same class in the HTML.

Comment: so it will still work if my buttons are under 2 different div?

Comment: @roy Yes buddy... It does.

Comment: @roy Can you make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

add a timeout function after showing the buttons, like this:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
         // add whatever code you want to reset 
}, 20000);
```

Comment: it is making the code work after 20 seconds whereas i want for 20 seconds